# My files and folders on my usb disk changed automatically to FILE format

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a 465 GB Maxtor USB external hard drive. I use it for games on my Xbox 360.

Today I turned on my Xbox 360, started XexMenu 1.1 and there were only a few games show on it.

I pluged-in my hard drive into my computer, went to my Games folder, and most of my folders were changed to the "File" format.

Disk backup isn't available because the disk is allmost full and 465GB isn't so small, please help!!!

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the data is gone.  `FIlE` isn't even a filesystem you sure that's correct?

Comment: According to your screenshot, your folders are still "Folders".  For the actual files, the file name extensions are missing, so Windows doesn't know what kind of files they are, and so they're shown as generic type "File" (because it's a file, not a folder).

Comment: The folders that have turned into files, that data is gone, and your unlikely going to be able to recover it.  I almost don't even want to help because your clearly using pirated copies of those games.

Comment: Found [this post](http://www.computing.net/answers/hardware/how-to-recover-my-folder-changed-to-file-type/88853.html) where it could be restored using a recovery software. Googling for  `folders changed to files` shows a lot of hits.